# "The problem under consideration" vs "The considered problem" vs "The problem considered"

Tags: word-choice, academia

I'm writing a research essay.

Is there any difference between the provided three variants? If so, which is best to use?

Comment: You're forgetting _The problem considered_. That's the best. _Under consideration_ is ponderous and better suited to a deliberative body, and *_considered problem_ is ungrammatical if it's intended to mean one that is actively being considered, rather than one that has already been considered.

Comment: Does the problem you are considering need to be labeled that way? What else would it be? If you are addressing a problem, then that's what you are talking about. As an argumentative reader, I'd be saying to myself, "Considered? Well why would he be addressing some problem *now* other than the one he introduced?"

Comment: If you mess around with consider and consideration, you got trouble, Houston. I'd go with: The problem being scrutinized or under scrutiny. Consideration is all wrong here. Not even worth trying to untwist it. It ain't great.

Comment: The three variants provided. // I've adjusted the title as the positioning of past participial adjectives is so well answered here, I've banked it as a specimen reference for further duplicates.

Comment: @Lambie I don't agree at all with your point of view; I had a math teacher once (a PhD) who would introduce questions or problems this way : "Let's consider the following <…>", "Let's consider this possibility", etc. There is no doubt that you can then talk  of _the problem considered_; in particular, in order to make precise what is being talked about, in a corrective statement you can say "…but the problem considered is somewhat different.". In this usage, "consider" is formal and means "to look at something with much  attention, seriously".

Comment: @LPH make precise says it all, about your comment.  Your professor was right. To consider something. But a research essay should do something stronger than to just "consider" a problem.

Comment: This should have been ported to ELL when it was first posted. Failing that the poster should also have been advised to use his academic facilities and search for the usage of these three forms. It is a hardly a suitable question for a site "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't say "the considered problem". Usually, a past participle used as adjective appears after the noun it modifies (*Practical English Usage*, second ed., Michael Swan, p. 405).

> We often use participles after nouns in order to define or identify the nouns, in the same way as we use identifying relative clauses.
>
> - *We couldn't agree on any of the* ***problems discussed***.
>   (=… *the* ***problems that were discussed***
>   (NOT …<s>*the* ***discussed problems***</s>.)
>   […]
>   *I got the only* ***ticket left***.
>
> ***Difference of meaning***
> A few past participles change their meaning with their position.
> Compare:
> an ***adopted*** child/the solution ***adopted***

There exists certain nouns for which "considered" is placed before, such as typically "opinion".

- a considered opinion, a considered thought, …

In this case the word means "that is the result of careful thinking". ([free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/considered+opinion))

As this sense of the participle is not that given in its use with "problem", you have to say "the problem considered".

The meaning is the same as that of "problem under consideration" because as explained above, this is equivalent to "***that is being considered***".